# Load balancing using PM2

Tags: javascript, node.js, load-balancing, pm2

I have problems load balancing a Node.js (10.32) simple script using PM2, on a machine with two CPU cores.

The script is the following:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  res.end("Hello World\n");
});
server.listen(81);
```

If I run `pm2 start -i max script.js`, the two child processes seem to launch successfully (according to `pm2 list`), but requests to `http://localhost:81` hang.

If I run `pm2 start -i max -x script.js`, the first child process is successfully launched, but the second restarts forever (with an EADDRINUSE error).

I checked with `lsof` and the port 81 is not used before running PM2.

Comment: what's your pm2 version?

Comment: The version is 0.10.8